# Sort subdocuments after a query in mongodb (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sorting

I am trying to sort my documents based on the `updated_date`. I'm using the following query

```
Collection.find({'_id':{$in:user['collectArray']}}).sort({ "updated_date": -1 }).toArray(function(err,collectionArray){...});
```

However I get an error saying `.find(...).sort(...).toArray is not a function`. So the basic idea over here is that I get all the subdocuments using there `_id's` and then sort the according to the `updated_date`.

I want to sort them while fetching it from the database itself rather than making a collection and then sorting them using JS

Comment: Does the sort work without .toArray() ?

Comment: Nope. I get an error saying that .sort takes only 1 argument

Comment: @user782400 Could you provide more code that doesn't actually work. How do you call this? How do you connect etc. Because this code just worked for me: http://jsbin.com/lejaririyo/1/edit?js

Comment: This thing is basically in a route. I call the route and this query is done. Could my code have issues because I'm only getting specific documents based on their ID's and then sorting?